# From struct, pointer to NULL, and back

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, null

```
typedef struct Element 
{
    int number;
    struct Element *right;
    struct Element *left;
} Element;

Element *newElement;
Element *head;
Element *pos;     
Element *current; 

void insert_Element()
{
    newElement = malloc(sizeof(Element));

    if (head==NULL)    
    {
      head = newElement;
      current = newElement;
      current->right = pos;
      //pos->left = current;
    }
}
```

The head of the double-linked-list should have a pointer to the next (`right`) element (which is `NULL`, but also `pos`). This works fine, but the pointer back(`left`) from `pos`/`NULL` doesn't work.
What did I do work; Is it even possible? 
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Where you allocate `pos`?

Comment: Nowhere. I did not know you have to. It worked without.
I thought that since I didn't allocate, that it would be equal to NULL

Comment: `pos->whatever` is dereferencing it. You cant dereference unallocated pointer.

Comment: The `newElement` should surely be a local variable to the `insert_Element()` function.  When the list is first created, you need to set `head`, `pos` and `current` to the new element.  You also need to set the new element so its left and right pointers are set.  Normally, your `insert_Element()` function would take the value to be inserted into the element (the number to be stored).  You have too many global variables for comfort.  Avoid them when you can.

Comment: what is the goal/role of `pos` ?

Comment: If `pos` is `NULL`, should the function put the new element at the end of the list?

Comment: `pos` is the "navigation". You select the Elements of the list with `pos` and edit (delete/insert) them. So the goal is to create a head which points to an "empty" `pos` and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The present version of the `insert_Element` function does not work unless `head` is `NULL` and `pos` is not `NULL`, and it does not set the `left` member of the new element. The purpose of the `pos` variable has not been stated, but appears to be used to point to the element before which the new element is to be inserted.  We could use `pos == NULL` to indicate that the new element is to be placed at the end of the list. Here is a version that does that:

```
void insert_Element(void)
{
    newElement = malloc(sizeof(Element));
    if (newElement == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    newElement->right = pos;
    if (pos != NULL)
    {
        /* insert before pos */
        newElement->left = pos->left;
        pos->left = newElement;
    }
    else if (head != NULL)
    {
        /* add to end of list */
        current = head;
        while (current->right != NULL)
        {
            current = current->right;
        }
        newElement->left = current;
        current->right = newElement;
    }
    else
    {
        /* add to empty list */
        newElement->left = NULL;
    }
    if (pos == head)
    {
        /* make it the start of the list */
        head = newElement;
    }
    /* make it the 'current' element */
    current = newElement;
}
```

---

It is better not to use global variables so much and uses function parameters instead.  Here is a version that uses no global variables and returns a pointer to the new element on the list (or `NULL` on allocation failure):

```
Element *insert_Element(Element **phead, Element *pos)
{
    Element *newElement = malloc(sizeof(Element));
    if (newElement == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    newElement->right = pos;
    if (pos != NULL)
    {
        /* insert before pos */
        newElement->left = pos->left;
        pos->left = newElement;
    }
    else if (*phead != NULL)
    {
        /* add to end of list */
        Element *current = *phead;
        while (current->right != NULL)
        {
            current = current->right;
        }
        newElement->left = current;
        current->right = newElement;
    }
    else
    {
        /* add to empty list */
        newElement->left = NULL;
    }
    if (pos == *phead)
    {
        /* make it the start of the list */
        *phead = newElement;
    }
    return newElement;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's possible you just need to allocate you `Element *pos`. Actually pos is equal to NULL and logically don't have pointer left or right, it's like looking for the toilet in a house that doesn't exist.

Comment: So how would I avoid this and actually make it work?

Comment: you just repeat what other people said several mins before you, making an answer we expect you also give a proposal to solve ;-)

Comment: @bruno You're right, I didn't see the other answers which are better than mine. Should I add an example next time ?

Comment: @twingoof yes, that makes the difference between a remark and an answer.

Comment: @bruno OK, my bad I didn't knowing that, I just started to look if I can help some people on my free time. Thanks for explaining me.